# Pandas written formula not evaluating and trigger error warning in Office 365

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm writing an excel formula referencing one sheet from another with pandas 0.25.0, but when I open the excel file it is not evaluated correctly.

If I open the file with LibreOffice the cell says Err:501, and in Office 365 it says there are errors in the file and tries to fix it, but ends up with empty cells after fixing.

The formula is not wrong, because if I edit the cell in LibreOffice Calc, enter a white space and remove it, followed by carriage return (enter), the formula suddenly works.

I tried both writing the formula directly as a string into the cell or in the dataframe, and using the DataFrame.write_formula, both not working.

Here is an example of the formula:

```
='my data'.$E4*'my data'.B4
```

or as defined in python:

```
cell_value = '=\'my data\'.$E4*\'my data\'.B4'
```

I make an excel file with multiple sheets as follows:

```
excel_writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_file_path, engine='xlsxwriter')
df_data.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name="my data")
df_formulas.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name="calculated data")
```

It is written to the cell with an ExcelWriter as such:

```
worksheet = excel_writer.sheets['calculated data']
worksheet.write_formula(cell_index, cell_value)
```

Or just simply with a df holding the strings of the formulas when writing `df_formulas`.

Both with the same outcome.

Please help if anyone has worked with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formulas need to be in US style syntax (see [Working with Formulas](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html) in the XlsxWriter documentation). In this case the formula should be (using "!" instead of "."):

```
cell_value = '=\'my data\'!$E4*\'my data\'!B4'

# Or changing quotes to make it clearer:

cell_value = "='my data'!$E4 * 'my data'!B4"
```

Update. Here is a working example:

```
import pandas as pd

df_data = pd.DataFrame([[10, 20, 30, 20, 15],
                        [10, 20, 30, 20, 15],
                        [10, 20, 30, 20, 15],
                        [10, 20, 30, 20, 15]])

df_formulas = pd.DataFrame()

excel_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df_data.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name="my data")
df_formulas.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name="calculated data")


cell_value = "='my data'!$E4 * 'my data'!B4"

worksheet = excel_writer.sheets['calculated data']
worksheet.write_formula(0, 0, cell_value)

excel_writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However, it did not solve the issue, and somehow it is converted from . to ! when I look in the output .xlsx. If I try changing it to ! in the text I get the `#NAME?` error in the cell. It sort of changed the outcome though, because now each cell shows 0 before I enter a space and remove it (or edit it in any other way).

Comment: You're right! It absolutely works (in Office 365). However, all the formulas are evaluated to 0 when I open the file in LibreOffice on Linux, and also the formulas are translated to (I guess European?) using . instead of ! at the moment of opening the file in LibreOffice Calc. In Office 365 the formula stays using ! even though I am in Europe. If I edit the cell (for example enter a whitespace and remove it, and save with hitting [Enter], then the formula evaluates also in Libre.

Comment: See this section of the XlsxWriter docs on Formula results: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#formula-results

Comment: So if I'm not mistaken, I would have to calculate the value in python and pass the value for each cell as the value parameter?

Comment: @simernes It depends what you want to do. 1. If your target is Excel then you don't have to do anything. 2. If your target is LibreOffice then you should investigate why the formulas aren't calculated. They should be. Perhaps upgrade LO to see if it is an issue that has been fixed. 2a. If your target is LO and an upgrade doesn't fix the issue then you will have to supply formula results along with the formulas.